# python generic redirect to URL

Tags: python, redirect

I am using a custom python framework. Not django or flask. Although it is similer to flask but does not have the redirect. After a sign up form POST. both the data and user go to the python script in the backend. What I want to know is in the return statement how do you redirect to a URL or web page. A django equivlent is

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
```

What I did was

```
return {Location : "/thank-you.html" }
```

This did not work. What my question is. What code do you use in the return to redirect to another webpage after the script has ended. Someone said something about headers. When I see what I am supposed to do then I can learn.

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What framework are you using specifically? 
You can use the webbrowser module to open up tabs if you are just using python

webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com') for instance

However, I recommend using a framework. Do you know JavaScript? I think you can redirect the user using JavaScript as well. window.location.replace("http://www.google.com"); would do the trick.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The framework I am using is custom that does not have redirects in place. Tried javascript. I am not able to post form data and direct the user to a different url. Tried a hundred times.

Comment: @studentofmsu Well if you are making web applications using python, Django and flask are the only good options out there. Django is arguably one of the best frameworks out there thanks to its speed and security. If the framework you are using doesn’t  have a redirect function, it is probably not very good from what I know about web development. I highly recommend using PHP for server side handling if you are not using Django. PHP is by far the most popular programming language for web development and you can essentially handle the backend side without the use of a framework. Best of luck!